# How to "unpack" this tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have a Python variable (database record) that prints as follows:

```
((79321L, Decimal('11.56125119')),)
```

What is the best way to print these two values? I want to do something like this:

```
print("Count: {}, Result: {}".format(cur.fetchall()))
```

Comment: If you're only expecting a single row as a result, then just use `fetchone()` instead and then you don't have to worry about unpacking this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [10]: a=((79321L, Decimal('11.56125119')),)
#a[0] is a tuple, use "*" to unpack a tuple when passing it as parameters:
In [11]: "Count: {}, Result: {}".format(*a[0])
Out[11]: 'Count: 79321, Result: 11.56125119'
```

see [how to unpack argument lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters), and **[format examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)**

or use the [old %-formatting operator](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python25/web/sequence-common.html):

```
In [13]: "Count: %s, Result: %s"%a[0]
Out[13]: 'Count: 79321, Result: 11.56125119'
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you explain `format(*a[0])`? I'm new to Python and I haven't used the `*` before.

Answer (score 2):

The left side unpacking needs to match the structure of the right side. So this will work:

```
((x, y),) = ((79321L, Decimal('11.56125119')),)
```

You have a single-item tuple whose contents is a two-item tuple

Answer (score 2):

If you're only expecting a single row as a result, then just use `.fetchone()` instead and then you don't have to worry unpacking it, eg:

```
print('Count: {} Result: {}'.format(*cur.fetchone()))
```

Or, if you have more, then loop over the cursor:

```
for row in cur:
    print('Count: {} Result: {}'.format(*row))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, for varitey:

```
value = ((79321L, Decimal('11.56125119')),)
a, b = list(value)[0]
```

Comment: Just `value[0]` is sufficient here - there's no need to build a `list` to unpack it